# Using ajax ActionLink in place of Html.ActionLink MVC

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

All,

I have an Html.Actionlink that calls a method in my controller and should return a partial view. My partial view is displayed within Index.cshtml, the partial view is _ServerStatusList.cshmtl.

View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ActionLink("Start", 
                     "StartServer", 
                      null,
                      new { @class = "startButton" })
}
```

Controller

```
[HttpGet]
        public PartialViewResult StartServer(Model model)
        {
            model.StartServer("server01");
            return PartialView("~/Views/Home/_ServerStatusList.cshtml", model.Servers);
        }
```

Right now upon clicking the start button all of the functionality works correctly as far as starting the server goes, but it returns the incorrect view. After clicking I get redirected to localHost/home/StartServer and it says "running" (as a started server should say in my server list) on a blank page. Then if I manually navigate to my server status page via the address bar it shows the server is running (as it should say) in my _ServerStatusList.cshtml.

I used an Ajax ActionLink in another part of my project to click a button and return a partial view. I tried it for this button too using this code.

```
 <input id="StartButton" type="image" value="submit" src="~/Images/start.png" alt="Start" height="25" />
@Ajax.ActionLink("Start", "StartServer",
                new AjaxOptions
                {
                    HttpMethod = "GET",
                    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                    UpdateTargetId = "CurrentView"
                }
            )
```

Clicking the button does not work but clicking on the word "start" does something similar to the Html.ActionLink. If I click the Start link it takes me to Index.cshtml, displays running in the area where the partial view should be, but does not load _ServersStatusList.cshtml. Again upon manual redirection everything is as it should be, running and correctly formatted.

How can I have the Ajax ActionLink use the image as the button, and upon clicking the image, return the correct partial view?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MVC is smart enough to find the view you need, so change your return PartialView from:

```
PartialView("~/Views/Home/_ServerStatusList.cshtml", model.Servers);
//To
PartialView("_ServerStatusList", model.Servers);
```

This should return the correct view :).

Comment: Thank you. Turns out I was looking way too deep into this -__-

Comment: :) I'm glad this solve your problem some times we only need another set of eyes and stack overflow have a lot.